# A tuple that only accepts some group of letters

Tags: python

I was trying to create a function that only recieves tuples that have elements only with the letters C,B,E,D. Arguments like CEE, DDBBB, ECDBE, or CCCCB. The input was going to be a tup = ('CEE', 'DDBBB', 'ECDBE', 'CCCCB') and using other functions that i created should convert them in a number that represents a position.

```
 def obter_pin(tup):
        pin=()
        posicao=5
        if not 4<=len(tup)<=10 or 'CBED' not in tup:
            raise ValueError('obter pin: argumento invalido')
        else:    
            for ele in tup:
            dig=obter_digito(ele,posicao)
            posicao=dig
            pin+=(dig,)
        return pin
```

Comment: Whats the output?

Comment: What is your error? What went wrong? I don't see the code you tried to enforce the tuple constraints.

Comment: @DaniMesejo the output is (1, 9, 8, 5), but the function works except for the part of raising the errror, it should raise a error if the tuple as other letters instead of C,B,E,D.

Comment: @Jab I don't have a error, I wanted to know how I can restrain the function to raise an error if the input has lettes besides  C,B,E,D in the tuple. Like, ('A','C'), i want to raise an error in that situatioon.

Comment: Echoing @OneCricketeer the for reopening a question is listed here -> [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `set` comparison:

```
>>> allow = {'C', 'B', 'E', 'D'}
>>> tup1 = ('CEE', 'DDBBB', 'ECDBE', 'CCCCB')
>>> tup2 = ('CEE', 'DDBBB', 'ECDBE', 'CCCCBA')
>>> allow >= set().union(*tup1)
True
>>> allow >= set().union(*tup2)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I like [@Jab's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69713813/5472354) much better, I just wanted to add another way of going about it:

```py
invalid = any(s.remove('C').remove('B').remove('E').remove('D') for s in tup)
```

### Much better:

```py
invalid = any(s.strip('CBED') for s in tup)
```

### Or:

```py
if ''.join(tup).strip('CBED'):
...
```

Comment: you could use `any(s.strip('CBED') for s in tup)`

Comment: Completely forgot about that. Even better.

Comment: You can use:    not ''.join(t).strip('CBED')

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one-line function.

**Function definition**:

```
def myfunction (t):
  return all(set(e).issubset('CBED') for e in t)
```

**Function in use**:

```
tup1 = ('CEE', 'DDBBB', 'ECDBE', 'CCCCB')
tup2 = ('CEE', 'DDBBB', 'ECDBE', 'GOO')
tup3 = ('CEE', 'DDBBB', 'ECDBE', 'ALPHA')

print(myfunction(tup1)) #True
print(myfunction(tup2)) #Fale
print(myfunction(tup3)) #Fale
```